# Logging into unix boks using public/private key encryption

Tags: unix, public-key-encryption

I am trying to login to my unix box using a public key(XYZ). I found out that I have to create a pair of public and private keys and add the public key to my server from where I will be logging in. But I am actually trying to login to the server from a seperate tool. The tool is being deployed into a seperate server. So adding the public key to that server would solve my problem? Is there method other than this to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to access machine B from machine A. Then generate public and private key of machine A. Then add the public key of machine A in the trusted keys list of machine B

Let me know if I am not understanding your question correctly

Comment: There is a machine A. There is a web application B. Now there is a button in this application on click of which a script must get executed on machine A. I have the public and private key setup on machine A. My problem is to call this script. I am using Ganymede SSH library to do this and I am tring to authorize with the private jey. The fn I am trying to us is Connection.authenticateWithPublicKey(user, pemPrivateKey, password). I am not able to send the pemPrivateKey which is a char[].

Comment: So you mean you can do ssh from B to A from command line but you are having a problem when you try to do through an application? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error messages. I think it wants the passphrase as it cannot get the privatekey. Is there any way I can get the private key by java code. i.e hit the box and get the private key. The other lookout here is to do an su without password.

Comment: I am not sure Suri about that. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ssh, then ssh-copy-id can help put your public key into the correct place on the unix box.

Comment: In the unix box all are fine as it has been in for a long time. The only question is how can it be used. Please refer to the comments on the post below.